# Batch resize and OUTPUT multiple images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resolution, dpi, batch-processing

I need to batch resize multiple images and thats really easy in Photoshop insert a folder and get a output in anther folder.

But i need this to output multiple images of all the images inside the folder is there a way to do this at once?

This is what i want:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have to run multiple actions. When you're recording an action, it doesn't look like you can use "Revert" as one of the commands.

So you run Action 1 on the source folder to get Output Size 1. Then you run Action 1 on the same source folder to get Output Size 2, and so on.

Comment: yep thats what i thought. So i need to run a action everytime i need a differed size.

Comment: But you can add both actions to a batch job.

Comment: @e100 How? Do you combine both actions into one? I don't see a spot to add more than one action in the dialog.

Comment: It's ages since I've done it and am away from PC. Yes, I think you combine both actions into one new one.

Answer (score 3):

[@Lauren Ipsum](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/16470/12189), in CS6 I managed to use `Revert` as a command in an action:
[image]

The trick is to save as a copy through the `Save As` dialog (or press `Ctrl+Alt+S` which will force save as a copy mode).

Additionally in the `Batch` window you should include a serial number to ensure files do not overwrite each other. As a result files will be named in a really strange way (the same serial will be appended to the file name many times e.g. `Filename02020202.jpg` for the fourth `Save` command) but at least this works.

Comment: Huh! I tried doing exactly that (save as) and I couldn't get Revert to show up. I also assumed that the OP would be saving each set to a different result folder, rather than stuffing everything into one folder with different file names. That would make me nuts, but I suppose it depends on your workflow.

Comment: The catch with `Save as` is that the saved file starts to be considered as the original document and thus you cannot revert. But if you check `As a Copy` checkbox it doesn't happen.

Comment: Oh THERE it is. That's clever!

Comment: When i use multiple `Save` command in the action, and use `Batch`, the problem @Const described happens to me too. The filename gets weird.
I've tried using `As a Copy` option on the `Save` command in the action but doesn't work. What he does is for each file on source folder, he put the increment number, instead putting the increment number on each `Save` command of the action. Anyone solved this?